# Search Product by SKU programatically using search criteria

Tags: magento2, sku, search-criteria

I need to search product programatically using search_criteria

```
public function search($storeId, $searchTerm, $searchOrder, $searchDir, $page, $pageSize, &$totalSearchResults, &$attrs_applied, &$attrs_available)
{

 $search_criteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

 $search_criteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");


$firstCharacter = substr($searchTerm, 0, 1);


if($firstCharacter == ":") {


   $filter = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('sku')
        ->setValue(substr($searchTerm, 1))
        ->setConditionType("sku")
        ->create();


} else {

   $filter = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
        ->setValue($searchTerm)
        ->setConditionType("like")
        ->create();
}

    $filterGroup = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter)->create();

    $search_criteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);

    $resultx = $this->_SearchInterface->search($search_criteria);

    $totalSearchResults = $resultx->getTotalCount();

    $products = $resultx->getItems();

    return $products;

}
```

but no return results, and throw exception

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Search\Request\EmptyRequestDataException): The request query and filters aren't set. Verify the query and filters and try again.

any idea?

Comment: why you  need `$search_criteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
`?

Comment: Please provide full code

Comment: ok i added the full code, i want to search by search term o by sku, 
first letter dependent

Comment: I donot think you have provided full code and i need to know  what is the type of `_searchCriteriaBuilder`

Comment: SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder

Comment: `SearchInterface`?

Comment: yes, SearchInterface $SearchInterface

Comment: i am  asking to provide full class/interface name also provide full code of that  your class

Comment: i finally use    $products_ = $this->_productRepository->getList($search_criteria);

Comment: but condition type "like" is not working. Only show the product where put the entire sku...